# Shared preferences user name

Tags: java, android, xml, editor, sharedpreferences

I have an app that I'd like to be able to let a user customize as far as setting their user name, email address and picture to the navDrawer from the preference menu. I'm not 100% sure how to do this though. I'm not sure how to set up the listeners to get the key from the preference screen. Also since these values have id's can they be replaced by the user from the preference they put in?

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want these values to persist through each use of the app, use SharedPreferences to save the values. Then retrieve and set them in your navDrawer adapter

```
 SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourActivity.this);
    pref.edit().putString("name", nameEditText.getText().toString()).commit();
```

To retrieve...

```
pref.getString("name", defaultValue);
```

Any additional "putString" using the same key will overwrite the data.

Hopefully this answers your question. If not I can help further. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) will help you too.

**EDIT** Refer to comments below.

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,R.drawable.ic_playlist, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
            super.onDrawerStateChanged(newState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
}
```

Comment: Not sure at all where to put this. I already have a settings fragment setup where my shared preferences are called. My issue is trying to have the edit text preference replace the dummy text that's already in the navigation drawer.

Comment: @JorellRutledge I edited my post to include a drawerToggle listener. This is what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work and crashes the app on launch. Maybe I'm not being clear with my explanation or needs. I will try to post some code later.

Comment: Yea some extra explanation and I can help you further!

Comment: OK I have this in the code (MainActivity): TextView userName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_name); preferences.edit().putString("your_name", userName.getText().to string()).commit(); But the app crashes on launch. Logcat says java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.get text() 'on a null object reference.

Comment: Edit your post with the code. In that comment you have toString method as "to string()" with a space...

Comment: I'm sorry but no. I'll be adding my code in a few minutes to my original question though.